# Can't get value from array "$wall = $wall->data->2016-04-16" in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I try to get $price, but something wrong. I think that 2016-04-16 can't be read. But I don't know how to fix it.

Here is result:

```
Array
(
    [success] => 1
    [data] => Array
        (
            [2016-04-16] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Nickola
                    [tag] => old
                    [price] => 206
                )

        )

)
```

Here is php:

```
<?php
    $wall = file_get_contents("XXX"); //request info
    $wall = json_decode ($wall, true); // convert JSON-string to array
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($wall); echo '</pre>'; //print array to check it OK.
    $wall = $wall->data->2016-04-16; // getting array with value I need
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($wall); $i++) {
    echo $wall[$i]->price; // print
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Should be `$arr['index']` not `->`

Comment: An `array` is not an `object`.

Comment: You passed in true as second parameter to json_decode thats why you need to access it using ['key'] instead of -> notation.

Comment: Thanks for reply. 
I tried this, but no result :(

`echo $wall[data][2016-04-16][name]; `

Comment: `$price = $wall["data"]["2016-04-16"]["price"];`
works! Thank your for your help!